# How do I limit the number of polygons in a layer?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, polygon

My code currently allows the user to have the ability to create many polygons at once. I would like it to instead erase the previous vector everytime the user decides to create a new one.

```
let drawSource = new VectorSource({wrapX: false}); 

let drawLayer = new VectorLayer({source : drawSource,})
this.map.addLayer(drawLayer);

let draw = new Draw({
  source : drawSource,
  type : GeometryType.POLYGON,
  style : new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
          color: "#f00",
          width: 1,
        }),
    fill: new Fill({
      color: "#300",
    })
  })
});
this.map.addInteraction(draw)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the source when a new drawing is started

```
draw.on('drawstart', function() {
  drawSource.clear();
});
```